# Unable to start Apache server on XAMPP with port available

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, local-web-server

I have XAMPP server installed on Windows 10. I changed ports the first time I used it and it worked fine until a few days ago. Now I get the error:

```
10:21:59  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:21:59  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:21:59  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:21:59  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:21:59  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:21:59  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:21:59  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I made sure it is NOT a port problem. I have checked all the ports using `netstat -na` and the ones I set in the config files are not being used. I also tried to force starting the service through the `service.msc` panel but I get `error 1`. I tried to run `setup_xampp.bat` and again nothing really happened. I disabled the IIS, and I'm running out of ideas. I also tried to run the control panel as administrator with the service installed, and in this case I get `Attempting to start Apache service..` for ever.
Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: which port is your xampp running?

Comment: @fmsthird I'm using port 8080for HTTP and 4432 for SSH. As I said, it worked fine with these ports until a few days ago, and they're all still available.

Comment: maybe try any other port except for 8080 and check

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Shell" button and execute the following command:

```
apache_start.bat
```

This will give you more details of the error.

In my case, the problem is in the file "php7ts.dll". I had to replace it.